# How to get the OpenSearch version of an AWS OpenSearch Serverless collection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, serverless, opensearch

When I send a get request to /_cluster/stats to a managed cluster, I can see the list of OpenSearch versions running in my nodes.

It's in nodes.versions:

```
{
  "_nodes": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
  },
  "cluster_name": "opensearch",
  // ...
  "nodes": {
    "count": {
      "total": 1,
      "cluster_manager": 1,
      "coordinating_only": 0,
      "data": 1,
      "ingest": 1,
      "master": 1,
      "remote_cluster_client": 1
    },
    "versions": [
      "2.3.0"
    ],
  },
  // ...
}
```

However, the same request to an OpenSearch serverless collection returns a 404 response.

I tried using the AWS CLI to get information about the collection with the command `aws opensearchserverless batch-get-collection --name <collection-name>`, but the response doesn't contain the cluster version:

```
{
    "collectionDetails": [
        {
            "arn": REDACTED,
            "collectionEndpoint": REDACTED,
            "createdDate": REDACTED,
            "dashboardEndpoint": REDACTED,
            "description": REDACTED,
            "id": REDACTED,
            "kmsKeyArn": REDACTED,
            "lastModifiedDate": REDACTED,
            "name": REDACTED,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "type": "SEARCH"
        }
    ],
    "collectionErrorDetails": []
}
```

How do I get the OpenSearch versions running on the nodes of an AWS OpenSearch serverless collection?